# How to calculate if a motor is capable for a load?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, torque

I am trying to figure out if a motor I have is capable of spinning a wheel. Here is all of the information I have:

MOTOR: 190 g.cm min.

WHEEL: 26 cm diameter, weighs about 59 grams

I imagine that I would have to calculate the linear speed of the wheel in order to convert it to the same units that the motor torque is listed in. However, I don't know if I am doing it correctly or what the next step would be to solve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [my answer to a similar question at the Robotics SE](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7796/calculating-required-torque/7799#7799). You are asking only about a motor and a **wheel**, and you do not give the weight of the vehicle (assuming there is one), so I cannot comment regarding vehicular motion.

Basically, if you assume friction is negligible, the torque a motor outputs is used to accelerate a load. Then you have to ask, "What is my desired acceleration?" A [Honda Civic] can accelerate 0-60mph in about 9 seconds, while a [1968 VW bus] went the same 0-60mph in 37 seconds. Both vehicles eventually get to the same top speed, but higher torque values give you a higher acceleration rate.

You can calculate your own desired acceleration rate by giving a top speed you would like to reach and a time limit in which you would like to achieve that speed. So, for example, if you wanted to get to 10rpm in 4 seconds, you would need:

$$
a = (\mbox{Top speed} - \mbox{Starting speed})/(\mbox{Time limit}) \\
a = (10\mbox{rpm} - 0\mbox{rpm})/(4\mbox{s}) \\
a = 2.5 \frac{\mbox{rpm}}{\mbox{s}} \\
$$

To be used in an equation, you typically have to convert to radians per second, which is easy knowing that $2\pi \mbox{radians} = 1\mbox{revolution}$ and that $1\mbox{min} = 60\mbox{s}$:

$$
\mbox{rpm} = \frac{\mbox{rev}}{\mbox{min}} \\
$$
$$
a = 2.5\frac{\mbox{rpm}}{\mbox{s}} = 2.5\frac{\mbox{rev}}{\mbox{min s}}\\
$$
Convert to $\mbox{rad/s}^2$:
$$
a = 2.5\frac{\mbox{rev}}{\mbox{min s}} * \frac{1\mbox{min}}{60\mbox{s}} * \frac{2\pi\mbox{rad}}{1\mbox{rpm}} \\
\boxed{a = 0.2618 \mbox{rad/s}^2}
$$

You can calculate your own target acceleration using the same method.

Once you have your target acceleration, you can use the torque formula:

$$
\tau = I \alpha \\
$$

Where $\tau$ is the motor torque **in Nm**, $\alpha$ is the acceleration **in $\mbox{rad/s}^2$**, and $I$ is the [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia) of your load **in $\mbox{kg m}^2$**. For a uniform disc, the moment of inertia about the center is given by:

$$
I = mr^2/2 \\
$$

where $m$ is the mass **in kg** and $r$ is the wheel *radius* **in meters**. This is how you would solve for the required (minimum) torque for your target application; as the question has been asked you do not know the acceleration you can achieve, so you rearrange the torque equation to solve for it as follows:

$$
\tau = I \alpha \\
\frac{\tau}{I} = \alpha \\
$$

Substitute in the definition for $I$ and you can determine your acceleration, **after you convert to standard units**:

$$
\tau = 190 \mbox{g cm} \\
\tau = 190 \mbox{g cm} * \frac{1 \mbox{kg}}{1000 \mbox{g}} * \frac{1 \mbox{m}}{100 \mbox{cm}} \\
\tau = 0.019 \mbox{kg cm} \\
$$
Here the torque is tricky - to get to Nm from kg-m you need to multiply by the gravitational constant, $9.81 \mbox{m/s}^2$:

$$
\tau = 0.019 \mbox{kg cm} * 9.81\mbox{m/s}^2 \\
\boxed{\tau = 0.1864 \mbox{Nm}}
$$
Divide the mass by 1000 to get to kg:
$$
m = 59 \mbox{g} * \frac{1 \mbox{kg}}{1000 \mbox{g}} \\
\boxed{m = 0.059 \mbox{kg}} \\
$$
And lastly divide the wheel diameter by 100 to get to meters **and** by 2 to get to a radius:
$$
r = d/2 \\
r = (26 \mbox{cm} * \frac{1 \mbox{m}}{100 \mbox{cm}})/(2) \\
\boxed{r = 0.13 \mbox{m}} \\
$$
Now, plug those values into the rearranged torque equation:
$$ 
\frac{\tau}{mr^2/2} = \alpha \\
\frac{0.1864 \mbox{Nm}}{(0.059 \mbox{kg} * 0.13^2 \mbox{m}^2)/2} = \alpha \\
\frac{0.1864 \mbox{Nm}}{0.0004986 \mbox{kg m}^2} = \alpha \\
\boxed{374 \mbox{rad/s}^2 = \alpha} \\
\alpha = 374 \mbox{rad/s}^2 * \frac{1 \mbox{rev}}{2\pi \mbox{rad}} * \frac{60 \mbox{s}}{1 \mbox{min}} \\
\boxed{\alpha = 3570 \mbox{rpm/s}} \\
$$

This is a lot, but it's not so unreasonable - [this article about motion control](http://machinedesign.com/sensors/basics-motion-control-part-2) has the figure below: ("back then" - 2000 - people didn't put graphics on the page, it's linked as Figure 2)
[image: Motor ramp]

Here you can see the motor accelerates from stopped to 2000 rpm in 0.12 seconds, for an acceleration of 16,667 rpm/s. Your motor is 3,570 rpm/s for your given load. You probably won't see rates quite that high due to friction, but it's a good ballpark.

So, in conclusion, you haven't stated what "adequate" is, but whatever your case, yes this motor will probably be good enough.

PS - again, [see my answer about climbing hills](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7796/calculating-required-torque/7799#7799) for more information on how ramps affect required torque. If you're building a vehicle.

Comment: This wheel is being used to launch ping pong balls, so it will not be under too much stress beyond just spinning the wheel.

Comment: Yeah I figured it was something like that or a large gyro when you had asked specifically about a wheel with no reference to a vehicle.

Comment: Reading through your response, I noticed that you said the motor should work. However, when I tried this out, the motor got very hot and started to smell bad. Is this normal for a motor to do? According to the information given, this motor should be able to handle 190g.cm with no load. I just assumed the "no load" detail didn't matter because it doesn't seem logical to give a "no load" torque, but does that affect the math at all? I think I might try to reduce the weight of the wheel by reducing the size of it, but in the end, I am looking for the highest linear speed.

Comment: Yes, this does affect the math, but how specifically it impacts the math depends on the exact motor [torque-speed curves](http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/elec/ref/serv_torque_speed_env2.png). You stated in your question, "MOTOR: 190 g.cm **min**", which I took to mean that the minimum torque was 190 g-cm. If you look at the image I linked above, that means I thought the value you gave was the lower-end torque on the far right of the plot. What you actually have is a no-load torque, so what you have called "min" is actually the *max* torque.

Comment: I still don't understand what changes I have to make to the math. As I am trying to find the maximum linear speed, I suppose I should start with the ideal mass - is there any way to do this? By the way, here is the motor (I am running it in a 12V config) - http://comingsoon.radioshack.com/radioshack-super-speed-9-18vdc-hobby-motor/2730256.html#.VYsQHflViko