# Motor for inverted rotary pendulum

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors

I'm building a rotary inverted pendulum to demonstrate reinforcement learning principles, however I have little experience with mechatronics. I will be building something similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cd96_8iwP6s).

However instead of plastic I will be using 10 mm aluminum tubes. The arm (horizontal) will be about 150mm long and the pendulum (vertical) will be about 150mm to 200mm with a little weight at the end (a few hundered grams).

So I have started my construction but the problem I have now is choosing a motor. I started looking through sparkfun and some chinese stores for motors until I realised that I have no idea what type or how powerful of a motor I need.

In order to avoid the complex calculations, I was hoping someone could give me a ball park estimation of the torque I would need, and the best type of motor for this application (stepper or a classic DC motor) considering my setup?

Comment: Related: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/understanding-required-torque-for-a-motor-lifting-a-weight and http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4186/how-to-calculate-if-a-motor-is-capable-for-a-load